# How to update doctrine in symfony2 app

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have symfony 2.0.15 and doctrine 2.1.7

This is my deps file

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.7

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.7

[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[doctrine-migrations]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/migrations.git

[DoctrineMigrationsBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMigrationsBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

But I want to get the doctrine 2.3 . how can I update that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, **Doctrine 2.3 is not stable**!

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.3.0-RC1

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.3.0-RC1

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.3.0-RC1

[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle

[doctrine-migrations]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/migrations.git

[DoctrineMigrationsBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineMigrationsBundle
```

Then update your vendors:

```
php bin/vendors.php update
```

My final advice is **Switch to composer**! It's a robust PHP dependency management system.

Comment: i tried composer aand i am not able to know how to use it. i installed it but i didn't worked. i am confused what to do with my old app.php file. do i need to remove it or or edit it

Comment: You can start reading this section of [Symfony installation documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/installation.html#updating-vendors).